# How can I add dashes in Any field on input and on backspace should remove

Tags: keyup

How can we add the dashes between text and when remove text characters it should not stick in loop.
like 44251-4548453-5

Comment: I have tried to search at stack over flow but did not found any proper solution so i generate this algorithm my self

Comment: ---html--
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="CNICText" />
---javascript code -----
$('.CNICText').keyup(function() {
var foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
if(foo.length==6 && !foo.includes('-'))
{ var d =foo.slice(0,5)+"-"+foo.slice(5,foo.length);
  $(this).val(d);
  }else if(foo.length >12)
{ var d =foo.slice(0,5)+"-"+foo.slice(5,12)+"-"+foo.slice(12,13); $(this).val(d);}
});